# mysql.query is not pushing to a table outside of its function

Tags: node.js

I have a variable named sortedPlayers (array) that im trying to push with my sql query function, however. It doesnt push to sortedPlayers at all.

Heres the function.

```
async function test (score, users, con) {
    
    let playerNames = [];
     
    let sortedScore = score.sort(function(low, high) {return high-low});
    let sortedPlayers = [1];
    
    for (let list of sortedScore) {
        
      console.log(list);
      
      con.query("SELECT * FROM ajparkour_scores WHERE score = " + list + "", function (err, result, fields) {

        console.log(sortedPlayers);
        
        // this is supposed to push to the variable sortedPlayers however it does not
        sortedPlayers.push(result[0].player);

      }); 
      
      console.log(sortedPlayers);
      
    }
    
    console.log("final sorted score: " + sortedScore);
    console.log("final sorted players: " + sortedPlayers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn

- What is a callback function
- How async/await works
- What is a promise?

Also using this query with per score variable makes your function slow.

So you can use:

- IN in your query to match it with multiple scores without a for
- Use query builders to avoid SQL injections.
- User ORDER BY in the query instead of built in sort.

```
const players = await con.query(`SELECT * FROM ajparkour_scores WHERE score IN (${scores.map(score => `"${score}"`).join(',')} ORDER BY score DESC`);
console.log("final sorted players: " + players );
```